# Can we mix past perfect, present progressive, etc. in conditionals?

Tags: tenses, conditionals

Is it acceptable / possible to mix past perfect, present progressive, etc. in conditionals?

In particular: The 2nd conditional (apologies to those who reject this common but by no means universal classification) is of the form

[If] + [NP₁] + [past simple] {+ NP₂} + [NP₁ or pro-form] + [would] + [infinitive] ...

Is it possible to use past perfect after the would?

Like:

- *If I were you I would have done that*

instead of the standard

- *If I were you I would do that.*

Comment: Stack Exchange was designed around having a single question per thread. This means it doesn't support multiple questions very well - for example, choosing an accepted answer is difficult if the best answer for one question is actually a poor answer for the second question. Please split your questions into separate threads.

Answer (score 0):

There will be *some* contexts where people could use either of...

> #1 *If I were you I would have done that*
> ...and...
> #2 *If I were you I would do that*
> interchangeably.

...but #1 will often be used simply because it's less of a mouthful than...

> 3: *If I **had been** you I would have done that*

...referring to a hypothetical ***past***, as opposed to #2 which refers to a ***"timeless" / present / future*** hypothetical scenario. In #1 (and #3), you've definitely already done something that I wouldn't have done (I'm *criticizing* what you did), but in #2 you probably haven't done anything yet (I'm *advising* you what to do).

---

Only extreme pedants would complain about the "mixed tenses" in OP's example #1. Google Books seems to have 2-3 times as many instances of the simpler (first) version of...

> [*If I **were** you I would have done it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If%20I%20were%20you%20I%20would%20have%20done%20it%22)
> rather than the "strictly correct" alternative...
> [*If I **had been** you I would have done it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22If%20I%20had%20been%20you%20I%20would%20have%20done%20it%22)

Comment: "had been you" sounds weird because this type of "being" is eternal. If someone had been you, they still *are* you. We're not in a "Freaky Friday" world where people swap places.

Comment: Suppose the contextually relevant aspect of ***you*** in my example was that the person I'm speaking to was *the lead actor* in some stage show, but refused to sign autographs for fans after the performance. *If I had been **the lead actor** [which **you** were] I would have done [the signings].* Nothing weird, linguistically.

Comment: That's very different, since roles can be temporary. Although present tense still sometimes works. I'm not saying that "If I had been you" is wrong, it just feels less necessary to have temporal agreement.

Comment: Well, where I come from, you'll much more likely hear *If I **was** you...* But I think you're missing the point. Apart from being a bit "posh", the subjunctive in this context *loses* "temporal consistency", because it's *timeless*. But for my money, there's next to no difference between ***If I'd['ve] been you...*** and ***If I'd've been in your shoes...***